# How to interlock divs?

Tags: css, html, pinterest, interlocked

I would like to interlock an undefined number of divs (as in Pinterest) from this:

```
++++++++ ********
+      + *      *
+      + *      *
+      + ********
+      +         
++++++++ 
~~~~~~~~ --------
~      ~ -      -
~      ~ -      -
~~~~~~~~ -      -
         -      -
         -      -
         -      -
         -      -
         --------
```

to this:

```
++++++++ ********
+      + *      *
+      + *      *
+      + ********
+      + --------
++++++++ -      -
~~~~~~~~ -      -
~      ~ -      -
~      ~ -      -
~~~~~~~~ -      -
         -      -
         -      -
         --------
```

Is it possible with CSS or other stuff?

Comment: why not buildin 4 seperate one-cell tables, with the heights and widths you want?

Comment: See this example http://jsfiddle.net/samsamX/YmU6J/1/

Comment: @Dineshkani, you should publish that as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been asked a million times on here.

Most folk use Masonry:

http://masonry.desandro.com/

Answer (score 1):

I refer this answer from [zessx answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14747800/how-do-i-align-a-div-to-top) thanks to zessx.

```
<h2>Without columns</h2>
<div class="box">1 Lorem Ipsum</div>
<div class="box">2 Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum</div>
<div class="box">3 Lorem Ipsum</div>
<p class="clear">&nbsp;</p>
<div class="box">4 Lorem Ipsum Lorem</div>
<div class="box">5 Lorem Ipsum</div>
<div class="box">6 Lorem Ipsum</div>
<p class="clear">&nbsp;</p>
<div class="box">7 Lorem Ipsum</div>
<div class="box">8 Lorem Ipsum</div>
<h2>With columns</h2>
<div class="column">
<div class="box">1 Lorem Ipsum</div>
<div class="box">4 Lorem Ipsum Lorem</div>
<div class="box">7 Lorem Ipsum</div>
</div>
<div class="column">
<div class="box">2 Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum</div>
<div class="box">5 Lorem Ipsum</div>
<div class="box">8 Lorem Ipsum</div>
</div>
<div class="column">
<div class="box">3 Lorem Ipsum</div>
<div class="box">6 Lorem Ipsum</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.box { 
width: 50px;
min-height: 50px;
background: #ccc;
margin: 3px;
padding: 3px;
float: left;
}
.clear {
clear: both;
height: 0px;
}
.column {
width:60px;
float: left;
}
```

[See Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Dineshkani/GCvdb/)